# Where are these LateX errors coming from?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I wrote a reasonably long document in LateX and am now trying to convert to PDF using the pdflatex command. I am getting very strange output though and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.
This is the output:
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
    entering extended mode
    (./plan of aproach.tx
    LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
    Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
    Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
    (./plan of aproach.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap            /pdftex.map}]
    [1] [1]
    ! Missing $ inserted.
     
                    $
    l.63 _
          “empower every person and every organization on the planet to achieve     ...

```
? ! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.64 

? ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.64 

? ! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.64 

? [2] [3]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.104 _
       What tool comes closest etc.

? ! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                  \par 
l.105 

? ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.105 

? ! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.105 

? 
Overfull \hbox (242.99614pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 104--105
[]$[]\OML/cmm/m/it/10                     hattoolcomesclosestinreplicatingtheidealrequirementstheco
ntractorhasstated; andwhatneedstobedonetomakeitaperfectmatch\OT1/cmr/m/n/10     ?[]
$ 
[4] [5])
Runaway argument?
{ Analysis phase The analysis phase will involve interviewing the var\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I have done research on what could be causing this and trid the following:
- Ruled out the "inserted missing $' is to offset something I am doing in math mode, since I don't use mathematics in this document
- Checked for | or _ , both seem not to be present in my document
- All braces seem to match up fine, so not sure where the runaway argument error is coming from either.

If anyone can help me figure this one out it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: :( FOund the problem. It helps when you actually compile the file you've made edits in, instead of another one with the same name but a different file extension. Feel free to vote delete :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please that curly brackets are closed properly. In that case you get these errors. Compiler does not know where the sentence or equation is completed